# Get root path of Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Flask extension from which I want to create a directory in the project's root path on the file system.

Suppose we have this directory structure

```
/project
    /app
    /tests
    /my_folder
    manage.py
```

my_folder should be created dynamically by the extension, which is a test utility and wraps the application under test in the /tests directory. However, I'm struggling to determine the project's root path within my extension.

For now, I am trying to guess the path from the run file:

```
def root_path(self):
    # Infer the root path from the run file in the project root (e.g. manage.py)
    fn = getattr(sys.modules['__main__'], '__file__')
    root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(fn))
    return root_path
```

This obviously breaks as soon as the tests are run from within the IDE instead of the manage.py. I could simply infer the project's root relative to the app or tests directory, but I don't want to make any assumptions regarding the name or structure of these directories (since multiple apps might be hosted as subpackages in a single package).

I was wondering if there is a best practice for this type of problem or an undocumented method which the Flask object provides (such as get_root_path).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`app.root_path` contains the root path for the application.  This is [determined](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/helpers.py#L619) based on the name passed to `Flask`.  Typically, you should use the [instance path](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.instance_path) (`app.instance_path`) not the root path, as the instance path will not be within the package code.

```
filename = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'my_folder', 'my_file.txt')
```

Answer (score 32):

`app.root_path` is the absolute path to the root directory containing your app code.

`app.instance_path` is the absolute path to the instance folder. `os.path.dirname(app.instance_path)` is the directory above the instance folder. *During development*, this is next to or the same as the root path, depending on your project layout.