# Save and access file on elastic beanstalk flask-app?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using `df.to_csv('data.csv')` command to convert a data frame to a CSV file.
 How can I access the same file `data.csv` from different module present in a different directory?
Directory Strucutre

- flask-app

  - application.py
  - services

    - processes.py
    - analysis

      - analysis1.py

`processes.py` converts a data frame to CSV(data.csv), and I want to use the `data.csv` file from `analysis1.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when is processes.py invoked? and where will "data.csv" be created?
If you're sure that "data.csv" file will be created and it will be created under "services" folder then you can easily access that file with relative path:

with open('../data.csv') as f:
       # do something

or you can access the file via absolute path and directory like this as it's answered here:
[Get Root Path Flask App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649703/get-root-path-of-flask-application)