# save downloaded files in flask root directory

Tags: python, flask

In the code below I am saving two csv files at desktop directory.

I want to store this files at root directory of my flask app, without
manually writing the file location.

How can I achieve this?

And if I want to access this files at any different endpoint, how can I access them,
which path should i  write here `df = pd.read_csv(path + angel.csv')`

```
@app.route('/')
def home():

    url = f"https://www1.nseindia.com/content/abc.csv.zip"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    stream = r.content
    filebytes = io.BytesIO(stream)
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)
    bhavcopy = pd.read_csv(zf.open(zf.namelist()[0]))
    bhavcopy.to_csv(r'C:\Users\91956\Desktop\BHAVCOPY.csv')


    df2 = pd.read_json(
    'http://margincalculator.angelbroking.com/OpenAPI_File/files/OpenAPIScripMaster.json')
    df2.to_csv(r'C:\Users\91956\Desktop\ANGELS.csv')

    return render_template('r2r3.html', dict2=dict2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get root path of Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649703/get-root-path-of-flask-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current working directory and append with your file name....
I guess the root path will be your current working directory if you have followed format of folder structure and all.
Hope this may help you....

```
filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'filename.csv')
```