# Given a Flask app object, how can I obtain the templates folder absolute path?

Tags: python, flask

After initializing the app, I would like to determine the absolute path of the 'templates' folder (to read a yaml file located inside it).

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

for example, I'm looking for something like this:

```
templates_path = app.get_absolute_path_to_templates()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
templates_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.template_folder)
```

Thanks to: [Get root path of Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649703/get-root-path-of-flask-application)